# Way in javascript regex to check for "this AND that WITHOUT this"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand how to do this. I'm doing a regex check to see if "Mobile" and "Safari" exist so I know if it's iOS, but the problem is that Android uses mobile Safari in some versions as well. So I had:

`(?=.*Mobile)(?=.*Safari).*`

But now how do I add "without Android in the string" to that? I tried to do a "not followed by" `(?!.*Android)(?=.*Mobile)(?=.*Safari).*` but that still matches until that's found which is not what I want.

Comment: I don't think you can use a single regex to check for the existence of multiple things that can be in any order.  If you insist on a regex, you could use multiple regexes and combine the logic from them.

Comment: And then we certainly reach the point where a regex is overkill :)

Comment: Hi Oscar, what exactly is not working for you about the expression you thought about? It doesn't match strings such as "Mobile Safari Android", isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use a regex for this?

To test if `a` is in `b`, use `b.indexOf(a) != -1`.
To test if `a` is *not* in `b`, use `b.indexOf(a) == -1`.

So your code should look like this:

```
if((str.indexOf('Mobile') != -1 || str.indexOf('Safari') != -1) && str.indexOf('Android') == -1)
```

Of course it would be much better if you used an existing browser sniffing library... or if you actually need to find out if a certain feature is available use code to test for that feature instead of a check for certain browsers or browser versions.

Comment: I dont want to use an entire library to just check for iOS and/or Android or Windows Phone 7. Our in house JS library is already massive and IE7 crawls so we don't like just throwing libraries in. And yes, I could have multiple conditional statements with a bunch of different `indexOf` calls, but i find a simple `ua.match(/(?=.*Mobile)(?=.*Safari).*/)` is a lot cleaner and it's also faster

Comment: Misusing a regex for something that should not be done with a regex is not clean at all. Besides that, the `indexOf` check is most likely much faster.

Comment: Also, im not checking for JS features, more looking for CSS based features (like differences in fixed positioning between these and other quirks)

Comment: Yes, you can detect those, too. Have a look at jQuery's `$.support` object or something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Comment: How is that *not* what regex is for? I have a long string and im looking for matches within the string? What else is it for? Also, no, regex is faster: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof

Comment: No, they all *support* fixed positioning, they handle it differently. Thats why I need to sniff and I don't need an entire library to check for extremely simple things

Comment: Regexes are meant to match patters, not to test if a string contains another "fixed" string. And how can you know that none of these browsers are going to change the way they handle it? (`$.support` *does* test for specific things btw - for example, if the box model is handled in the old-IE way or correctly)

Comment: I know because im targeting specific versions. iOS 4 for example doesnt do fixed positioning the expected way, iOS >=5 does, Android 2.x does it, but its not fluid. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/ and Modernizr has no mention of fixed. So, thats just one major case where it wouldn't. Also things like autocomplete are handled differently (some remove the text on click/tap, some don't). There's no other way or checking _how_ these perform. I don't care about any of the things $.support/Modernizr checks for.

Comment: Also: "a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means for 'matching' (specifying and recognizing) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, *or* patterns of characters". It's more performant, cleaner, and more concise, why are you against it so much?

Comment: If you just need a small hole in a wall, do you use a jackhammer for it? Of course you *can* do so and it would kind of work (let's not get into aestethics :P) - but why use a way too powerful tool for such a simple job?

Comment: If I saw a complicated regex like the one provided by other answer(s) in this situation, my thought process would be, "What in the world is this doing here and what is it trying to accomplish?" Either you can add a comment to clarify that, assume no one will be confused, or use the (common-usage) indexOf with some logical operators. The performance difference is so insanely minor that I consider it pointless to fret over, though. It's like debating `++a` over `a++` where `a` is a number.

Comment: Why use regex? It's shorter, faster and (for those of us who have attended jackhammer school) more readable. 8^)

Answer (score 2):

Easily done. Just add an anchor and a negative lookahead:

```js
re = /^(?=.*Mobile)(?=.*Safari)(?!.*Android).*/i;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the start-of-line `^` makes a difference for this?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Sure. Given the subject string: `"Android Mobile Safari"` The expression without the `^` will successfully match at every position after the first A in `Android` up to the position immediately before the M in `Mobile`. Adding the `^` anchor forces all three lookaheads to match _only_ at the start of the subject string.